# pandas monthly resample 15th day

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I am trying to resample to monthly values but with respect to 15th day

I checked the timeseries [offsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) documentation but there is only

M   month end frequency
SM  semi-month end frequency (15th and end of month)
MS  month start frequency
SMS semi-month start frequency (1st and 15th)

while I need just the 15th day

Something like

```
2000-01-15 8.7
2000-02-15 6.9
2000-03-15 15.8
2000-04-15 12.4
```

I tried with pd.offsets.MonthBegin and MonthOffset with no results

Comment: What are input sample data?

Comment: Do you need aggregate data or filter only `15 day` like `df = df[df['date'].dt.day == 15]` ?

Comment: daily data for example. I trying to aggregate the data

Answer (score 8):

Aggregate by starts of months `MS` and then adjust the resampled time labels by `loffset` parameter:

```
df1 = df.resample('MS', loffset=pd.Timedelta(14, 'd')).sum()
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=15, freq='5D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(15)}, index=rng)  
print (df)
             a
2017-04-03   0
2017-04-08   1
2017-04-13   2
2017-04-18   3
2017-04-23   4
2017-04-28   5
2017-05-03   6
2017-05-08   7
2017-05-13   8
2017-05-18   9
2017-05-23  10
2017-05-28  11
2017-06-02  12
2017-06-07  13
2017-06-12  14

df1 = df.resample('MS', loffset=pd.Timedelta(14, 'd')).sum()
print (df1)
             a
2017-04-15  15
2017-05-15  51
2017-06-15  39

df1 = df.resample('SMS').sum()
print (df1)
             a
2017-04-01   3
2017-04-15  12
2017-05-01  21
2017-05-15  30
2017-06-01  39
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is deprecated in pandas `1.4.2` and comes with a warning `FutureWarning: 'loffset' in .resample() and in Grouper() is deprecated.`

The recommended alternative is do first resample normally, then add a `Timedelta` to the index:

```py
df1 = df.resample('MS').sum()
df1.index += pd.Timedelta(14, 'd')
```

Answer (score 0):

For python 3.11 and Pandas 2.0.2, the following works to resample on mid-month timings.

```
from datetime import datetime
times = ['2022-06-15 00:12:23', '2022-06-18', '2022-07-03', '2022-07-18']
data = [10, 100, 1000, 10000]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=pd.to_datetime(times), columns=['test'])

period = '1M'
start = pd.Timestamp(year=2022, month=5, day=15)
offset = pd.Timedelta(days=start.day - 1, hours=start.hour, minutes=start.minute, seconds=start.second, microseconds=start.microsecond)
df.index = df.index - offset
rs = df.resample(period).sum()
rs.index = rs.index + offset + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
rs
```

Gives me:

```
            test
2022-07-15  1110
2022-08-15  10000
```